# Is my FOR LOOP working properly and, if not, how to fix it? Bricks game with computer

Tags: c#, for-loop, output

As I am learning programming using C#, I try to solve the following problem, for me it looks a bit difficult, please help:
Given n bricks. You and the computer make moves alternately. Per turn one  can take 1, 2 or 3 bricks.
One who has nothing to take - loses. Implement the game with the computer.
The computer makes moves randomly (without analyzing the winning strategy), however, if he has the move that is the last to win, he makes it.

Below, is the code that I wrote so far. The program is working but does not show the result, when a certain number of bricks was used. Not sure how to fix this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BricksGame
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CH();
        Console.WriteLine("To exit please press any key ...");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    public static void CH()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of bricks: \n");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nHow many bricks to take (1, 2 or 3)?");
            int user = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            n = n - user;
            if (i < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nComputer lost!");
            }
            else
            {
                Random rn = new Random();
                int comp = rn.Next(1, 4);
                Console.WriteLine("\nComputer took:" + comp);
                if (i < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou lost!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here I post the re-worked code

```
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nHow many bricks to take (1, 2 or 3)?");
            int user = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            n = n - user;
            Console.WriteLine("The remaining number of bricks is: {0}", n);
            if (n < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nComputer lost!");
            }
            else
            {
                Random rn = new Random();
                int comp;
                if (n <= 3)
                {
                    comp = n; //For computer to take the remaining bricks
                }
                else
                {
                    comp = rn.Next(1, 4);
                }
                n = n - comp;
                Console.WriteLine("The remaining number of bricks is: {0}", n);
                Console.WriteLine("\nComputer took:" + comp);
                if (n < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou lost!");
                }
            }
        } while (n > 0);   
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your for loop always does `n` iterations and does not stop then he game is over. There are several other problems in your code, but you should first re-think your loop and how to determine the end of the game.

Comment: Ditch the `for` loop and use a `while(true)` loop. Add a `break;` on condition met, after `Console.WriteLine()`, where the condition needs to be `if (n < 1)`. You forgot to subtract the Computer take from `n`. The Random generator could (should) be a static field.

Comment: You're checking `i` instead of `n` in a couple of places: `if (i < 1)`, which will never be true since the iteration condition is `i > 0`. You're also not subtracting the computer's bricks from `n`. Also, you should just create a single instance of `Random` instead of creating a new one each time. Since it uses the clock as a seed value, if you happen to instantiate inside a fast loop, it will return the same number several times in a row. It also might be nice if you added a line after each action that showed the number of bricks left.

Comment: Also, it's too easy to win the game :) If the Computer could take up to 5 bricks instead of 3, maybe... + There's no check on how many bricks the user inputs. You could set the user input value to 3 if the value happens to be > 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nHow many bricks to take (1, 2 or 3)?");
        int user = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        n = n - user;
        if (n < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nComputer lost!");
        }
        else
        {
            Random rn = new Random();
            int comp;
            if(n <= 3)
            {
                comp = n; //For computer to take the remaining bricks
            }
            else
            {
                comp = rn.Next(1, 4);
            }
            n = n - comp;
            Console.WriteLine("\nComputer took:" + comp);
            if (n < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou lost!");
            }
        }
    } while(n > 0);
```

Put this instead your for loop. Haven't test it, sorry, I have write it here directly without opening Visual studio, so please try if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I re-implemented the program and now it works properly. I appreciate you.

Comment: @ShepV.  Etiquette is to mark this as "the answer" and probably upvote its usefulness.  (Since you say "now it works properly").  This prevents this question coming up under "show unanswered questions" in SOF and also gives some more reputation to the person who helped you.